# Dynamic feed of an iframe and get height

Tags: jquery

my brain is about to crash and can´t get this... ¿can anyone help me?

I´m trying to create a page where the content is loaded dinamically into a #section-master iframe which slides up and down to hide old content/show new content when I click menu buttons (a.launcher). The proble, is that I cant get de correct height of the dinamically content-loaded "master-section"

The index.php code is like this:

```
    <div>
        <a data-url="main-about.php" href="#" class="launcher">ABOUT</a>
        <a href="#contacts" class="scroll-to animated bounceInDown">CONTACT</a>
        <a data-url="main-home.php" href="#" class="launcher">HOME </a>
        <a data-url="main-works.php" href="#" class="launcher">WORKS</a>
</div>


    <section id="section-master">
        <div class="accordion"
            <iframe onload="setIframeHeight(this.id)" width="100%" frameborder="0" id="master-iframe" name="master-iframe" src="main-home.php" </iframe>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And this is how I´m trying to get the effect

```
    get_div_height();
    $(".launcher").each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    el.click(function() {
        get_div_height();
        alert(get_div_height);
        $( '#section-master' ).animate({marginTop: -div_height}).delay(300).queue(function (next) {
            $("#master-iframe").attr("src", el.data('url'));
            next();
        }).queue(function (next) {
            $( '#section-master' ).animate({marginTop: 0});
            next();
        }); 
    })
});
function get_div_height(){
    var div_height = $('#section-master').height();
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: And where is the relation to php?

Comment: Sorry, that php tag was by mistake ;) thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your help, I got the solution just a few minutes after by myself. Post the code here just in case is helpful to somebody:

Just called get_div_height function each time the #section_master was called and thats it ;)

```
// Launch content into iframe 

$("#section-master").load(function(){
    get_div_height();
});

$(".launcher").each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    el.click(function() {
        var sHeight = $('#section-master').height();
        $( '#section-master' ).animate({marginTop: -sHeight}).delay(300).queue(function (next) {
            $("#master-iframe").attr("src", el.data('url'));
            next();
        }).queue(function (next) {
            $( '#section-master' ).animate({marginTop: 0});
            next();
        }); 
    })
});

function get_div_height(){
    var div_height = $('#section-master').height();
}
```